# customized PHP code formating in Netbeans IDE

Tags: netbeans

Netbeans IDE has code format feature that can be launched using the "Format" item in the "Source" menu. how can I customize this "Format" operation so my formatted code will be in the style that I define. I could not find any special documentation in Netbeans Help or online WIKI.

Answer (score 3):

Tools-Options-Editor-Formatting-(Language:PHP)

Don't forget to configure all categories (Not `Tabs and Indents` only)

Answer (score 0):

I think right now this is our best bet http://www.netbeans.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=163030

Comment: I hope it will be usable in netbeans 6.7.0.0.0.0.1. cause I really need it.